# How to add rows from one datagridview to another empty datagridview by some conditional in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using visual studio 2017, C#, Windows Forms to create an index for words in a list of sentences.

I have two datagridview:

`dataGridView2`: This grid has a single column where each row contains a worded sentence.

`dGvTopics`: This grid has one column for every word that is repeated in the first sentence (first row) in `dataGridView2`, the column header text is the *word*.

Goal: I want to click button to categorize, inserting a row in `dGvTopics` for each row in `dataGridView2` (sentences), place a copy of the sentence as the value for that column if the sentence contains the column header text.

My Code is:

```
private void btnClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dGvTopics.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(dGvTopics.Columns[i].HeaderText))
        {
            this.dGvTopics.Rows.Add();
            this.dGvTopics.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned any error or problems you have encountered, though it seems obvious you will get a more direct answer if you are more specific in the area you need help with. I have edited your post to make it easier to understand, please review my edit to make sure it matches your expectation

Comment: Some example data or screenshots would also help complete the picture

Comment: also, did you mean to copy across the whole sentence for each column, or do you just want the count of the times that word appears in the sentence?

Comment: Thank you for carefully correcting my question. Yes that was what I meant.
I would like to have sentences under each column that contain the name of that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We can discuss later why you are doing this at all, there are easier ways :)

You need to understand that there are two dimensions to iterate here, the rows in `dataGridView2` and the columns in `dGvTopics`, this means you will need two looping statements, not just one.

Your current code is looping through the *Rows* in `dataGridView2` but only for the number of columns that are in `dGvTopics` which is a bit confusing.

> **PRO TIP:** *Don't* use arbitrary single character variable names that have no meaning. Yes `i` is ubiquitously used to represent *index* in code you will find around the web, that doesn't mean it is good practice. `i` should be reserved for lazy programming where there is a single, single dimension array that you are iterating over, in your example there are 4 different levels of arrays that you accessing, the meaning of `i` is now ambiguous.
>
> > Instead of `i`, use a meaningful variable name like `columnIndex` or `topicIndex`. That way when each line is reviewed in isolation, the code is more self documenting. I would even accept `t` or `c` in this code, taking the first initial from the conceptual variable meaning will help spot common errors where the wrong *indexer* is used for the wrong array.
>
> Yes this make the code *wordy* and long, but we're not constrained by memory space in the same way as our developer ancestors, this doesn't change the size of the final executable, strive to make your code self-documenting.
>
> > If you are programming in a code-memory-constrained environment, like for micro-controllers, or tiny chipsets, then still use meaningful short variables, not arbitrarily selected characters.

Applying the above recommendation highlights this first issue:

```
for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dGvTopics.Columns.Count; columnIndex ++)
{
    if (dataGridView2.Rows[columnIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(dGvTopics.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText))
    {
        this.dGvTopics.Rows.Add();
        this.dGvTopics.Rows[columnIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = dataGridView2.Rows[columnIndex].Cells[0].Value;
    }
}
```

Now we can see that each iteration is moving down the rows, but across the cells at the same rate, meaning that only the cells in a diagonal formation will even be compared and have a value.

The next issue is that because you are only creating a row when the comparison returns `true`, this means that the rows in `dGvTopics` might be less than you are expecting, which means less than the value of `i` (or `columnIndex`) which will raise an `IndexOutOfRangeException` the next successful iteration *after* any comparison that fails.

You can avoid this problem by iterating over the rows and columns separately and adding one row in `dGvTopics` for every row in `dataGridView2`.
We can also make the code clearer by saving a reference to the `currentSentence` rather than referencing the sentence through the array indexers.

```
private void btnClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove any existing rows, we will reprocess all records.
    this.dGvTopics.Rows.Clear();

    // Iterate over the rows in the list of sentences.
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; rowIndex ++)
    {
        // Create one topic row for every sentence
        // row index will always be valid now.
        this.dGvTopics.Rows.Add();

        // save the sentence value to simplify the comparison code.
        string currentSentence = dataGridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        
        // iterate over the columns in the topics grid
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dGvTopics.Columns.Count; columnIndex ++)
        {
            if (currentSentence.Contains(dGvTopics.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText))
            {
                this.dGvTopics.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value = currentSentence;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

It's not easy to comprehend *why* you want to do this or how this information will be used. In general for manipulating values in cells we generally recommend that databinding techniques are used instead, that way you do not access rows and cells anymore or but the underlying objects that they represent.

- demonstrating this is outside of the scope of this question, but it's an avenue worth researching when you have time.

In solutions like this where there are two grids that represent the same logical component, (in this case each row in each grid represents the same sentence value) the underlying dataobject might be a single list, where one property on the object is the sentence and each topic column is a property on the *same* object.

Importantly, using databinding means that the next process that needs to use the information that you have displayed or edited in the grids can do so without access to or knowledge about the grids at all... Something to think about ;)

### Update

This code may result in many empty cells in the *topics* grid. We could instead only add rows as they are needed, but to do this will require a lot more effort.

> **NOTE:** Grids render all the cells for each *row*, In the last couple of rows, there may still be empty cells if at least one of the cells for that row has a value.

```
private void btnClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove any existing rows, we will reprocess all records.
    this.dGvTopics.Rows.Clear();

    // Iterate over the rows in the list of sentences.
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; rowIndex ++)
    {
        // save the sentence value to simplify the comparison code.
        string currentSentence = dataGridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        // iterate over the columns in the topics grid
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dGvTopics.Columns.Count; columnIndex ++)
        {
            if (currentSentence.Contains(dGvTopics.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText))
            {
                // first we need to know what row index to add this value into
                // that involves another iteration, we could store last index in another structure to make this quicker, but here we will do it from first principals.
                bool inserted = false;
                for(int lookupRow = 0; lookupRow < this.dGvTopics.Rows.Count; lookupRow ++)
                {
                    // find the first row with a null cell;
                    if(this.dGvTopics.Rows[columnIndex].Value == null)
                    {
                        this.dGvTopics.Rows[lookupRow].Cells[columnIndex].Value = currentSentence;
                        inserted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!inserted)
                {
                    this.dGvTopics.Rows.Add();
                    this.dGvTopics.Rows[this.dGvTopics.Rows.Count-1].Cells[columnIndex].Value = currentSentence;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forced to don't use the database. So I took this approach.

Your coding tips helped me a lot.

The story is this: I upload a continuous text file to my program. The program separates the repetitive words and places the sentences under each word. This way we will have a categorization of sentences given for each word.

Thanks again, good luck

Comment: Does it answer your question though?

Comment: Yes it works.
But in the new Datagridview,you get a lot of empty cells. Is there any way to delete these cells?

Comment: Sort of, you could shift up the results to remove empties, but unless all columns have the same number of rows, there will always be empty cells at the bottom. A Row is the object that holds cells, You can't for instance a row that only has one cell in it, the grid must render all cells in a row.

Comment: I've added a variation to the code that tries to reduce the empty cells, I haven't actually tried to compile this but I hope that explains the difficulty in using a `DataGridView` to achieve the output you are expecting. Also note that data binding doesn't mean you have to use a database...

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Mr Chris Schaller,
According to his description, the final code changed as follows after compiling:

```
private void btnClassify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remove any existing rows, we will reprocess all records.
    this.dGvTopics.Rows.Clear();

    // Iterate over the rows in the list of sentences.
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        // save the sentence value to simplify the comparison code.
        string currentSentence = dataGridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        // iterate over the columns in the topics grid
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dGvTopics.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            if (currentSentence.Contains(dGvTopics.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText))
            {
                // first we need to know what row index to add this value into
                // that involves another iteration, we could store last index in another structure to make this quicker, but here we will do it from first principals.
                bool inserted = false;
                for (int lookupRow = 0; lookupRow < this.dGvTopics.Rows.Count; lookupRow++)
                {
                    // find the first row with a null cell;
                    if (this.dGvTopics.Rows[lookupRow].Cells[columnIndex].Value == null)
                    {
                        this.dGvTopics.Rows[lookupRow].Cells[columnIndex].Value = currentSentence;
                        inserted = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!inserted)
                {
                    this.dGvTopics.Rows.Add();
                    this.dGvTopics.Rows[this.dGvTopics.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[columnIndex].Value = currentSentence;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You spent a lot of time to answering my question. So, as soon as my reputation reached 15, I voted for your answer.
Now I accept your answer.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I appreciate that, just helping you on your way, good luck on your programming journey!